# How to redirect user with database callback function - HAPI

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, hapi.js

I want my user to be shown a loading icon until the database responds, then be redirected to the correct page.

My code is along the lines of:

```
// handler
function handler(request, reply) {
  reply.view('loading') // show loading with css

  // do database stuff...

  // database callback function
  function db_callback_function() {
    reply.redirect('user/page') // after db responds, redirect. 
  }
}
```

Hapi says that I can only use the reply interface once:

```
Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: reply interface called twice
```

So how can I redirect my user **after** the database loads?

Edit: I know that I need to show the loader using front end. I just don't know how my back end would tell my front end when to redirect.

Comment: If your backend is just a REST interface then you need to add a spin-loader with JS in your frontend.

Answer (score 1):

One request can only respond once.
You should do the "loading stuff" on your frontend side not backend.

So when you sent an HTTP request you should mark your state as loading.

For your example code, server code should modify to:

```
// handler
function handler(request, reply) {
  // reply.view('loading') <- REMOVE THIS LINE

  // do database stuff...

  // database callback function
  function db_callback_function() {
    reply.redirect('user/page')
  }
}
```

In that case, when your frontend received the response, then it will redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: How would the front end know when to redirect to the appropriate page?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, in short -- you'll not have a whole page for loading state, just do it by js and css.

Comment: You say *when your front end received the response*. How will it do that? How will my front end receive the response?

Comment: 1. Send request
2. Use JavaScript and CSS to show some loading animation
3. Response back
4. Page will redirect to the appropriate page according to your code

Comment: hmmm ... also, don't you expect a response from an HTTP request?

Comment: Here's what I don't understand: **how does my front end know when to redirect?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152354/discussion-between-ori-marash-and-david-lee).